# Allow user to change password

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update, change-password

I'm trying to allow logged in users of my site to be able to change their password which will then be updated in my database. When I click the submit button, I get 'Unknown column '[username]' in 'where clause'. I've tried multiple things and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm a beginner with PHP so don't have an expansive skillset, so I'm not sure what the problem could be. If anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it, thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once ("db_connect.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/functions/functions.php');


$oldpw = ($_POST['oldpw']);
$newpw = ($_POST['newpw']);
$conpw = ($_POST['conpw']);
$currentpw = $_SESSION['password'];

if ($_POST['change'] == 'Change') {
    if ($oldpw && $newpw && $conpw) {
        if ($newpw == $conpw) {
            if ($db_server){
                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                $oldpw = salt($currentpw);
                // check whether username exists 
                $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE 'username'= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
                $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                if(!$result){
                    $message = "<p class='message'>Error: Coud not connect to the database.</p>" ;
                }else{
                    $newpw = salt($newpw);
                    $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$newpw' WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['username'] . "";
                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                            die("Insert failed. " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                    $message = "<p class='message'>Your password has been changed!</p>";
                    // Process further here 
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            }else{
                    $message = " <p class='message'>Your current password is incorrect.</p>";
            }
        }else{
            $message = "<p class='message'>Your new passwords do not match.</p>";
        }
    }else{
        $message = "<p class='message'>Please fill in all fields.</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the html I've used:

```
<form action='change-password.php' method='post' id="register-form">
     <?php echo $message; ?>
         <input class="password-field" type='password' name='oldpw' value='<?php echo $username; ?>' placeholder="Current Password"><br />  
         <input  class="password-field" type='password' name='newpw' placeholder="New Password"><br />
         <input class="password-field" type='password' name='conpw' placeholder="Confrim Password">
         <input class="button" type='submit' name='change' value='Change' />
 </form>
```

Comment: To find out the real error, you should use `echo mysqli_error($db_server);` instead of your `Error: could not connect...` custom message.

Comment: I am guessing it is because the username `$_SESSION['username']` is not surrounded in single quotes as a SQL string in that query...

Comment: Strings have to be in quotes. Also why are you storing the password plaintext?

Comment: This will  be true also of the subsequent `UPDATE` statement for both the username and `$newpw`  See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois There is a `salt()` function in there on the passwords. I would assume that is doing some salt+hash operation...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He or she is hashing the current password and then he or she is doing nothing with it. He or she has to hash the new password.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It's there:   `$newpw = salt($newpw);` right before the `UPDATE` that uses it.

Comment: This would be an excellent time to start learning how to use [`prepare()/bind_param()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi, which would avoid the SQL quoting problems while also improving security. There are some examples [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/541091)

Comment: I've added the single quotes to $_SESSION['username'] in the update statement and echoed the mysqli_error, now when I submit the form i get 'unknown column '[username]' in 'where clause'

Comment: @BethanyGordon - that means that there's no column called `username` in that table. What is its structure?

Comment: Please also edit above to show the current state of your code. The `unknown column '[username]'` message is suspect, and suggests the wrong thing may have been quoted (the column name rather than the value, for instance)

Comment: there is, I have 4 columns in the table called ID, username, password and datelog

Comment: @BethanyGordon I see you updated the error message above, but can you please also edit to update the SQL statements as you currently have them?

Comment: I've got it working! the working statements read: $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE 'username' = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'"; and $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$newpw' WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";

Comment: This can't actually be working as intended: `WHERE 'username' =`  That is a column name and should be unquoted ``WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'....`

Comment: `if (!$result)` successfully checks if the query _failed_ but doesn't check if it didn't return any rows (because username doesn't exist). for that, you would need to check `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` to know if you should proceed to do the `UPDATE`.

Comment: It's silly to do this in the comment thread-- I'll type it up as a proper answer below...

Comment: It updated the salted password in the database, but I've unquoted username, and added if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) before $newpw = salt($newpw) and its still works

Comment: @BethanyGordon There are some other things - like verifying that the old password was submitted correctly before update. I added that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem you're facing is the fact that the SQL string values for `$_SESSION['username']` and `$newpass` were not properly single-quoted in the SQL strings. For a run-down on when and how to quote inside SQL statements, have a look at [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks).

Turn on error reporting, always when developing code. At the top of your script:

```
// Disable this when your code is live...
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

So Using your current code, quoting the *strings* but not the *column names* would appear as below.

```
$oldpw = salt($currentpw);

// check whether username exists 
$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' AND password='$oldpw'";
//----------------------------------no quotes^^^^^^^--single-quotes^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Also adds a check that $oldpass is correct!

$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if(!$result){
    // This is ambiguous. It should probably show an error related to the query, not connection
    $message = "<p class='message'>Error: Coud not connect to the database.</p>" ;
}else{
    // This should only be done if a row was returned previously
    // Test with mysqli_num_rows()
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $newpw = salt($newpw);

      // Adds single quotes to the username here too...
      $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$newpw' WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
      mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
            die("Insert failed. " . mysqli_error($db_server));
      $message = "<p class='message'>Your password has been changed!</p>";
      // Process further here 
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
       // Username or password was incorrect - do something about that
    }
}
```

This can be further improved [using prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).  Your hashed password should be safe from SQL injection, [but it is highly recommended to get into the habit of using prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), as they are necessary for other cases where strings derive directly from user input to offer sufficient protection against SQL injection.

That would look like:

```
// Prepare the select statement to check username and old password
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_server, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND passowrd = ?");
if ($stmt) {
  // Bind parameters and execute it
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_SESSION['username'], $oldpw);
  $stmt->execute();

  // num_rows works here too...
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    // Ok to update...
    // Prepare another statement for UPDATE
    $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($db_server, "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE username = ?");
    if ($stmt2) {
       // Bind and execute
       $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $newpass, $_SESSION['username']);
       $stmt->execute();
    }
    // Error updating
    else echo mysqli_error($db_server);
  }
}
// Error selecting
else echo mysqli_error($db_server);
```